# Error adding a record with a Django model from script

Tags: python, django

I had a lot of problems tryng to fix a problem in a project I made to learn Django so I decide to make it from scratch AGAIN and go directly for the 'mistake'

So, steps:

1. Create a folder named wapi
2. Inside that folder execute virtualenv winenv
3. Activate the virtualenv
4. Install django with pip
5. django-admin startproject subastas
6. python manage.py migrate (then create superuser)

Then I run the server and everything works.

After that I run python manage.py startapp ah

in the folder ah in models.py I write this models

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Producto(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    id =  models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    umbral = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Cotizacion(models.Model):

    #fecha = models.DateTimeField()

    minimo = models.FloatField()
    maximo = models.FloatField()
    promedio = models.FloatField()
    cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.Producto.nombre
```

Then I register those in the folder /ah/admin.py as:}

```
from django.contrib import admin
from ah.models import Producto, Cotizacion

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Producto)
admin.site.register(Cotizacion)
```

in the folder /subastas/ I register in settings.py the app in installed apps

I run again the migrate command and runserver and I can see everything running, I even add a Producto to the database.

So far, so good, everything works. but..... I want to create a record not from the django admin site but with a pyton script. I am tring this:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "subastas.settings")
import django
django.setup()
from ah.models import Producto, Cotizacion



Rose = Producto.objects.get(id=124105)
cot = Cotizacion(10, 11, 15, 10, Rose)
cot.save()
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "registrarProducto.py", line 4, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\4user\Desktop\proyectosP\wapi\winenv\lib\site-packages\d
jango\__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyectosP\wapi\winenv\lib\site-packages\d
jango\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyectosP\wapi\winenv\lib\site-packages\d
jango\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyectosP\wapi\winenv\lib\site-packages\d
jango\conf\__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyectosP\wapi\winenv\lib\importlib\__ini
t__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'subastas'
```

Someone asked me why I put the django.setup() header,  If I dont put that I get this error, And I red in other stack questions that is mandatory to put that header if we want to work with models in scripts

```
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TAB
LESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment
 variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing s
ettings.
```

Comment: Because if I dont put that header I got this other error   % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TAB
LESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment
 variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing s
ettings.

Comment: And you are running this script from where? Because the error message should be obvious: `sys.path` doesn't contain the path to your application module and hence it cannot be found.

Comment: It's better to use django management commands to interact with django models. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: The script is in the same folder from ah/

Comment: Then you can write `from .models` instead of `from ah.models`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up this app in your project
https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

Create a python folder scripts in your project root. 
Add a script with add_cotizacions.py

```
from ah.models import Producto, Cotizacion

def run():
    Rose = Producto.objects.get(id=124105)
    cot = Cotizacion(10, 11, 15, 10, Rose)
    cot.save()
```

From your project root run command

```
python manage.py runscript add_cotizacions
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, now I have another error but it is ment for another question :)